# How to append character to the end of line using SED?

Tags: text-processing, sed, csv

I have the following text:

```
serverName: NZRC222
total: 8.46 GB
serverId: 259695

serverName: NZRC333
total: 50.13 TB
serverId: 260582

serverName: NZRC555
total: 9.31 TB
serverId: 260956
```

My desired output would be:

```
serverName: NZRC222,
total: 8.46 GB,
serverId: 259695,

serverName: NZRC333,
total: 50.13 TB,
serverId: 260582,

serverName: NZRC555,
total: 9.31 TB,
serverId: 260956,
```

Basically, I want to generate a `csv` file which can be imported to the Excel.

When I go with :
`sed '/\w.*/ a ,' file` I get this:

```
serverName: NZRC222
,
total: 50.13 TB
,
serverId: 260582
,

serverName: NZRC333
,
total: 9.31 TB
,
serverId: 260956
,
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace non-empty lines with the line and comma:

```
sed 's/.\+/&,/'
```

or

```
sed -E 's/.+/&,/'
```

`&` stands for the matched text, which is the whole line here.

Comment: Bingo, this also works :) `sed 's/\w.*/&,/g'` Didn't know for `&`.Thanks for quick answer!

Comment: Why not just `s/.$/&,/`? why the `g` flag at all?

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver, I’ve dropped the anchors and the `g` (force of habit). Replacing only the last character is even better, but I’ll let you add that if you want... Sato’s answer is even better.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
sed '/./ s/$/,/' file
```